# AWS Lambda for .Net Microservices

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am very new to AWS and have a requirement to develop Microservices in .Net & deploy them on Lambda.But I see 2 options when I include AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio-Lambda Functions & Lambda Serverless Application(over Asp.Net CORE Web API).
[image]

I am not sure which template to pick for having individual and independent microservices.
Could anyone please suggest,I could find the exact information online.

Comment: Try one of the many blogs on the subject eg http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/dotnet-core-aws-lambda-serverless-application/

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out..i created a solution with mulitple AWS Serverless application.Used the CF script for deploying/publishing the endpoints.The AWS Lambda Project was overwriting the existing end point each time a Method was added.